# ForEach unknown outOfRange issue

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

So, I have a View that shows lessons and I try to iterate through array with `lessons.count`

```
struct LessonView: View {
    var lessons : [Lesson]
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<lessons.count) { index in
                   //some code with using lessons[index]
            }
        }
}
```

When I debug my code it keeps throwing "index out of range" at part where I want to get access to element of array. In debug mode with breakpoint I see that it's really trying to get access to out of range element (to index = 2, when there's only 2 elements), but otherwise I also see that `lessons` array has only 2 elements, therefore `lessons.count` should return 2 instead of 3. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or am I missing something obvious?

[screenshot of variables, 2 values in array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qEz9.png)

I know that proper way to solve this is just do something like `ForEach(Array(lessons.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, lesson in}`
But know I'm interested in my mistake.

Comment: You cannot use dynamically changing ranges with SwiftUI's `ForEach` like this.

Comment: @jnpdx so why it's going for 3rd itearation (with index = 2), when `lessons.count` always returns 2

Comment: Watch “Demystify SwiftUI” Apple has a section there about why this is unsafe.

Comment: @Keril It's inherently unsafe. Undefined behavior is to be expected.

Comment: `ForEach` is a `View` not a for loop, you need to give it all the data so it can watch for changes

Answer (score 0):

As @lorem mentioned above, [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) is really helpful. You better take a look at this video.

In short, the concept behind SwiftUI is that it manages the elements (Views) via `Identity`.

> ForEach(0..<lessons.count)

By doing above, you're telling SwiftUI to use the offset in this half-open range to identify the Views. It seems good enough. But on the other hand, you also need each View to have a unique id during the lifetime of the view. So, the offset must be a constant rather than a dynamic range, that's why you got the crash.

---

You found the solution: it was providing a stable identity with `element.id` where id must be hashable. And from now on, you're safe to iterate through the array.

> ForEach(Array(lessons.enumerated()), id: \.element.id)

However, it's not necessary if the `lesson` model conforms to the `Identifiable` protocol. You're now free to access the `lesson` element and can omit this id parameter.

```swift
ForEach(lessons) { lesson in
    ...
}
```

Comment: And what is the safest thing I can do if I need an additional lesson index?

Comment: You can use `enumerated`. It is guaranteed if you don't accidentally access the item by lessons[index].